# inner product with zero in hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Is inner product of $<v, 0>_\mathcal{H}=0\ v \in \mathcal{H}$ on any Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: Of course.  Look at the definition of inner product.  What properties from that definition can you use to prove $\langle v,0 \rangle = 0$ ?  This proof is up to you, not us.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\alpha\langle v, 0 \rangle = \langle \alpha v, 0 \rangle = \langle v, \alpha 0 \rangle = \langle v, 0 \rangle \\
\mbox{so } \langle v, 0 \rangle \equiv \langle x, 0 \rangle\ \forall x \\
\therefore \langle v, 0 \rangle \equiv \langle 0, 0 \rangle \equiv \|0\|^2 \equiv 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: What property did you use to move the $\alpha$ from the first to the second argument? Doesn't that assume symmetry?

Comment: The above proof works for a real Hilbert space. The same proof would work for a complex Hilbert space with the appropriate substitutions.